# Dnsmasq Not Redirecting IP to URL

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dns

I installed Pi-Hole on my network. I added a redirect to the bundled Dnsmasq server to redirect a domain to an internal IP.

The redirect is working and I can visit the URL on my phone and other computers that haven't visited the site before and each one is redirected to the correct IP.

But it isn't working on my Windows computers that have visited , they think the URL is still pointing to the real IP of the domain and not the one that Dnsmasq is redirecting.

**What's going on? Why can't Windows get the new IP from the server?**

I've cleared the DNS cache on my computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!!!

Avast Antivirus has a feature called "Real Site" where they silently force your computer to use their DNS servers to protect you against DNS hijacking. This overrides any custom DNS servers you have.

Disabling this fixed this. Go to Protection -> Real Site and disable it "Indefinitely".